# PHP как создать Thumbnail'ы?

Tags: php, wordpress, файлы, thumbnails

Добрый день!
У меня есть папка на сервере с исключительно png картинками.
Мне нужно в другую папку с помощью PHP сложить их уменьшенные версии чтобы веб-страница быстро грузилась. Картинок не очень много, около 70 штук. Просьба к сообщениям прикреплять код т.к. я первый раз встречаюсь с thumbnails.
P.S: У меня последняя версия PHP и насколько я знаю, там встроена библиотека GD.
Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Сжатые? Или меньшие по ширине и высоте?

Comment: http://cubiq.org/create-fixed-size-thumbnails-with-imagemagick / http://www.dototot.com/imagemagick-tutorial-batch-resize-images-command-line/ / http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: уменьшенные в размере

Comment: желательно без установки дополнительных библиотек

Comment: А что есть? Imagemagic, gd?

Comment: есть gd поскольку он встроен в мою версию php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php (Example)

Comment: Мне нужно сразу все картинки в папке сжать - то есть изменить размер

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: У вас два примера кода один ходит по папке, фторой уменьшает картинку.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$sourceFolder = '/path/to/sources/';  // директория с исходниками
$destFolder   = '/path/to/dest/'      // директория назначения

$newImageWidth   = 100;  // итоговая ширина изображения
$newImageHeight  = 100;  // итоговая высота изображения

foreach (glob($sourceFolder . '*.png', GLOB_BRACE) as $origImagePath) {
    $origImageInfo = pathinfo($origImagePath);

    list($origImageWidth, $origImageHeight) = getimagesize($origImagePath);

    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth, $newImageHeight);
    imagealphablending($newImage, false);
    imagesavealpha($newImage, true);

    imagecopyresampled($newImage, imagecreatefrompng($origImagePath), 0, 0, 0, 0, $newImageWidth, $newImageHeight, $origImageWidth, $origImageHeight);

    $newImagePath = $destFolder . $origImageInfo['basename'];
    if (file_exists($newImagePath)) {
        unlink($newImagePath);
    }

    imagepng($newImage, $newImagePath);
}
```